# No root partition in the Debian example partition scheme

Tags: debian, partition, fstab

I am trying to follow the example partition scheme in https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/ch04s10.en.html

Somehow, the fstab file doesn't specify a root partition. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays, on Linux, the root partition is not strictly needed in `/etc/fstab` because it is mounted on `/` at boot time owing to the `root=` [boot parameter](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bootparam.7.html).

To know your current boot parameters, just `cat /proc/cmdline` (details on the output with [`man kernel-command-line`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/kernel-command-line.7.html)).

If you don't have a line for `/` in `/etc/fstab`, you can still figure out what is your root partition with this command:

```
awk '$2 == "/"' /proc/mounts
```